# Remove selected file(s) by clicking the remove link from the input file multiple and submit to Controller's parameter

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, file-upload, asp.net-core-mvc

How do I post the file(s) to the parameter in my Controller? 
I have a breakpoint for my Action in my Controller and I want to see if the files (after removed some unwanted files) can be post through my Controller.

Right now, even if I hit upload button, the breakpoint will give me a null value instead of the name of the files.

After clicking the submit button, the files displayed in the Console (F12) is alright, but for the breakpoint in my Controller is showing null.

What should I do to post the files to my Controller?

Comment: Yes, I have added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Your ajax code is sending files with the name of `fileList[]` , but your server expects a parameter with a name of `parameterIsHere` and the Type should be `UploadFiles`.
2. It seems that you doesn't send a CSRF token

How to fix :

**Approach A :**

1. Server Side:  change your action method as below (Note the Type and the name):

   ```
   [HttpPost]
   public IActionResult UploadAction(List<IFormFile> fileList)
   {
        // ...
   }
   ```
2. Client Side : add `CSRF` token and change the name of fields to be `fileList`:

   ```
   function sendModifiesList(e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       fileList.forEach(function(file,idx) {
           formData.append(`fileList`, file);      //// name should be `fileList` 
       });
       formData.append("__RequestVerificationToken",$("form input[name='__RequestVerificationToken']").val());
       console.log("These files will be posted: ", formData.getAll("fileList"));
       /*************** EDIT *************************/
       // Get the url from the form's action attribute
       let url = document.forms[0].action;
       let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
       // Create a POST request
       request.open("POST", url);
       // Set up an onload handler to report status
       request.onload = function() {
           if (request.status == 200) {
               console.log("Uploaded!");
           } else {
               console.log("Error " + request.status + " occurred when trying to upload your file.");
           }
       };
       // Send the form to the server 
       request.send(formData);
       /************ END EDIT ***********************/
   };
   ```

**Approach B :**

if you don't care the name, you could simply use the `HttpContext.Request.Form.Files`  to get the files:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult UploadAction()
    {
         var files= HttpContext.Request.Form.Files;
         // ... 
    }
```